# Issue with substrings and ToUpper in VB

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a small program for class and the error is, specifically in relation to line 18, that:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

I'm confused as to what is going wrong in the code. What about this loop, specifically, is failing?

```
Do
        CurrentPositionOfAtSymbol = StartingTweet.IndexOf("@", CurrentPositionOfSpace)
        CurrentPositionOfSpace = StartingTweet.IndexOf(" ", CurrentPositionOfAtSymbol)
        StartingTweet.Substring(CurrentPositionOfAtSymbol + 1, CurrentPositionOfSpace - CurrentPositionOfAtSymbol).ToUpper()
    Loop Until CurrentPositionOfAtSymbol = -1
```

Here's the entire code block:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim Tweets As New ArrayList
    Dim Temp As String = ""
    Dim UserName As String
    Dim NumberOfCharacters As Integer
    Dim StartingTweet As String
    Dim FinishedTweet As String
    Dim AmountOfTweets As Integer
    Dim CurrentPositionOfAtSymbol As Integer = 0
    Dim CurrentPositionOfSpace As Integer = 0
    Dim UppercasedName As String

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        'place tweet into variable
        StartingTweet = TweetTextBox.Text
        'make all others usernames uppercase
        Do
            CurrentPositionOfAtSymbol = StartingTweet.IndexOf("@", CurrentPositionOfSpace)
            CurrentPositionOfSpace = StartingTweet.IndexOf(" ", CurrentPositionOfAtSymbol)
            StartingTweet.Substring(CurrentPositionOfAtSymbol + 1, CurrentPositionOfSpace - CurrentPositionOfAtSymbol).ToUpper()
        Loop Until CurrentPositionOfAtSymbol = -1
        'place username before tweet
        FinishedTweet = UserName + Environment.NewLine + StartingTweet
        'add date & time to tweet
        FinishedTweet = FinishedTweet + Environment.NewLine + DateAndTime.DateString
        'add the tweet to the arraylist
        Tweets.Add(FinishedTweet)
        'display all tweets in the arraylist
        TweetedTweetsBox.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine + " " + Environment.NewLine, Tweets.ToArray)
        'clear out the textbox for a new tweet
        TweetTextBox.Text = ""
        'Increase and display number of tweets
        AmountOfTweets = AmountOfTweets + 1
        NumberOfTweets.Text = AmountOfTweets.ToString
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'ask the user for name and store it as a string
        UserName = InputBox("What is your username?")
        'replace name spaces with hyphens
        UserName = UserName.Replace(" ", "-")
        'make name totally lowercase
        UserName = UserName.ToLower()
        'adds @ to username
        UserName = "@" + UserName
        'displays username
        UserNameDisplay.Text = UserName
    End Sub

    Private Sub TweetTextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TweetTextBox.TextChanged

        'find the amount of characters in the text box 
        NumberOfCharacters = Len(TweetTextBox.Text)
        'output the amount of characters in the text box
        CurrentCharacterAmount.Text = NumberOfCharacters.ToString
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Do
    CurrentPositionOfAtSymbol = StartingTweet.IndexOf("@", CurrentPositionOfSpace)
    CurrentPositionOfSpace = StartingTweet.IndexOf(" ", CurrentPositionOfAtSymbol)
    StartingTweet.Substring(CurrentPositionOfAtSymbol + 1, CurrentPositionOfSpace - CurrentPositionOfAtSymbol).ToUpper()
Loop Until CurrentPositionOfAtSymbol = -1
```

Your code executes the 2nd and 3rd lines of the nested block even if `CurrentPositionOfAtSymbol` is `-1`.

Also, `Substring` returns a new instance of a string, it does not mutate the original value (strings are immutable in .NET). Same with `.ToUpper()`.

Finally, while using verbose identifiers helps program maintainability, being too verbose hinders readability, consider using names like `atSymbolIndex` instead of `currentPositionOfAtSymbol`, for example.

**UPDATE**: If I'm understanding your code correctly, it's meant to do this:

1. Find all twitter `@`-prefixed usernames and convert them to uppercase.
2. Extract them from the text and move them to the start of the tweet.

So this tweet:

> Hello @username1 how are you? @username2 says hello

Becomes this:

> @USERNAME1 @USERNAME2 Hello how are you? says hello

I would do this using a simple state-machine parser that works by reading each character from the input (it has two states: `in-username` and `in-nonUsernameText`) and converting it as it goes along. I'll use C# as I'm more comfortable in that language, and you should be able to follow it fairly easily:

```cs
public static String ProcessTweet(String inputText) {

    Boolean isInUserName = false; // as this is a 2-state machine, we don't need a more complicated state indicator (such as an enum)

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); // this is the output buffer
    StringBuilder userNames = new StringBuilder(); // this is the buffer that contains only usernames

    using( StringReader rdr = new StringReader(inputText) ) {

        Int32 nc; Char c;
        while( (nc = rdr.Read()) != -1 ) { // read each character until the end of the input
            c = (Char)nc;

            if( isInUsername ) {

                if( Char.IsWhitespace( c ) ) {
                    sb.Append( c );
                    userNames.Append(' '); // separate usernames
                    isInUserName = false;
                } else {
                    c = Char.ToUpperCase( c );
                    userNames.Append( c );
                }

            } else {

                if( c == '@' ) {
                    userNames.Append('@');
                    isInUserName = true;
                } else {
                    sb.Append( c );
                }
            }//if
        }//while
    }//using

    String output = userNames.ToString() + sb.ToString();
    return output;
}
```

Comment: So how would I modify just that small segment of the string?

Comment: @Falcon87456 I won't answer your question directly, but consider the case where a tweet contains multiple `@`-prefixed usernames, your code is very brittle (it doesn't handle a wide variety of inputs).

Comment: That's why I had it looped; so that the multiple @-prefixed usernames would all be replaced. I'm not sure why that wouldn't work. And I've switched the Until CurrentPositionOfAtSymbol = -1 to after the Do vs being after the Loop.

Comment: The goal is just to make the usernames uppercase, not to move them to the front, but I'll look through your answer and see what I can figure out.

Comment: @Falcon87456 Your code had the comment "'`' place username before tweet`" so I made that assumption.

Comment: It was just for the original submitter's name.